# Create FormData excluding not provided input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data, form-data

I submit a form manually via jQuery. I use FormData with all input elements from this form.
See code below:

```js
$("#submit-form").on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var form = $('#submit-form')[0];
        var data = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my-best-handler",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 60000
        });
    });
```

One of input elements is file and it's optional to set it. When it's not set, I don't need to use it in FormData and be sent with other elements to request handler.
The problem is that currently it will be sent even if it's not set.

I'm curious how I can exclude it from FormData if it's not set.
In worst case I can create FormData manually like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045034/1262265).
But I hope there is "black list" like approach by removing just not set file from FormData OR any other elegant way.

**Update**:
I came with the following solution:

```
if (!$("#input-file").val()) {
    data.delete('input-file');
}
```

Comment: may be `data.delete('file_name');` ?

Comment: Another approach might be disable the input (if empty) before setting FormData. The delete method above does make sense though

Comment: @charlietfl Could you please share any example code how to disable file input if empty?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Could you please post your comment as an answer? By the way it's what I need.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev done, thanks

Comment: What is it uploading if no file is chosen?

Comment: @Barmar empty binary for multi part with "noname" file name :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `delete()` function to remove your field

```
var form = $('#submit-form')[0];
var data = new FormData(form);
if (!$("#input-file").val()) {
  data.delete('input-file');
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be conditional depending on whether a file has been selected?

Comment: Yes, need to be checked for empty file

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Thanks. I updated my question with exact code I will use.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling input approach.

Disabled form controls never get submitted

```
$("#submit-form").on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // disable before creating FormData
        $(this).find(':file').prop('disabled', function(){
             return !this.files.length;
        });

        var form = $('#submit-form')[0];
        var data = new FormData(form);
```

As mentioned in comments should re-enable in ajax success callback

Comment: Thanks. I think an approach with delete looks more easy to maintain. Please let me know if you think differently or your approach has advantages over delete one. I updated my question with exact code I will use.

Comment: Either way should work. The `delete` intent is very easy to read though

Comment: You should re-enable it after the form submission is done, otherwise the use won't be able to select a file later.

Comment: @Barmar right you are...wasn't thinking about re-use